# Receive data from Arduino. I'm having a hard time converting this

Tags: arduino, sensor

Image data is received and transmitted from Arduino through spi communication. In Arduino
By reading through `temp = SPI.transfer(0x00);`
Pass it to `Serial.write(temp);`

The value D8 and D9  seem to be working properly, because if clauses recognize the beginning and end

Now,in the process of recognizing this on the PC,
Confusion arises here because of unknown parts.
The incoming data is hexadecimal.
Isn't this a code that normally converts byte-type data into hexadecimal? Even though the data is received, the end of the image is not recognized.

thank you for reading

```
data = ""
stop = 0
while True:
    if s.isOpen():
        #print("opened")
        lines = s.read()  
        out_hex = ['{:02X}'.format(b) for b in lines] 
        
        #print(out_hex)
        h_temp = ""
        
        for h in out_hex:
            print(h)
            if h_temp == "FF" or h == "D9":
                data += h
                stop = 1
                print("Found footer")
                break
            else:
                data += h
                h_temp = h
                #print(h)
    if stop == 1:

        break


data_b = binascii.a2b_hex(data)
with open(r"buffer.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data_b)
```

1)the transferred msgs is `ACK CMD SPI interface Error! END`..
I will try again.

2. I got a msg :

```
ACK CMD ArduCAM Start! END
ACK CMD SPD inside Error! END
ACK CMD CM
```