# Error received from Arduino (related to arducam)

Tags: arduino

Do you know the following error?

```
ACK CMD ArduCAM Start! END
ACK CMD SPD inside Error! END
ACK CMD CM
```

I'll add more details about the situation below.

[Receive data from Arduino. I'm having a hard time converting this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110277/receive-data-from-arduino-im-having-a-hard-time-converting-this)

thank you for reading